# Qt6 cross compile for STM32MP157 perl error

Tags: qt, perl, cross-compiling, stm32

I am building Qt6 for STM32MP157

Qt sources downloaded v6.1.2
Platform: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
STM32 SDK version: v2.0.0

The same build succeed for host machine (to generate qt host tools)
But when I run it with toolchain file for stm32mp157, it fails with error by perl on syncqt.pl line 55:

```
use English qw(-no_match_vars );
```

The error message is as follows:

```
-- Running syncqt for module: 'QtCore' 
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "ur_PK",
    LC_PAPER = "ur_PK",
    LC_MONETARY = "ur_PK",
    LC_NAME = "ur_PK",
    LC_ADDRESS = "ur_PK",
    LC_NUMERIC = "ur_PK",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "ur_PK",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "ur_PK",
    LC_TIME = "ur_PK",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
Can't locate English.pm in @INC (you may need to install the English module) (@INC contains: //usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.1 //usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.30.1 //usr/lib/perl5/5.30.1 /opt/st/stm32mp1/3.1-openstlinux-5.4-dunfell-mp1-20-06-24/sysroots/x86_64-ostl_sdk-linux/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.1/x86_64-linux /opt/st/stm32mp1/3.1-openstlinux-5.4-dunfell-mp1-20-06-24/sysroots/x86_64-ostl_sdk-linux/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.1 /opt/st/stm32mp1/3.1-openstlinux-5.4-dunfell-mp1-20-06-24/sysroots/x86_64-ostl_sdk-linux/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.30.1/x86_64-linux /opt/st/stm32mp1/3.1-openstlinux-5.4-dunfell-mp1-20-06-24/sysroots/x86_64-ostl_sdk-linux/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.30.1 /opt/st/stm32mp1/3.1-openstlinux-5.4-dunfell-mp1-20-06-24/sysroots/x86_64-ostl_sdk-linux/usr/lib/perl5/5.30.1/x86_64-linux /opt/st/stm32mp1/3.1-openstlinux-5.4-dunfell-mp1-20-06-24/sysroots/x86_64-ostl_sdk-linux/usr/lib/perl5/5.30.1 .) at /home/dyasin/repos/qt6/qtbase/libexec/syncqt.pl line 55.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/dyasin/repos/qt6/qtbase/libexec/syncqt.pl line 55.
CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/QtModuleHelpers.cmake:206 (message):
  Failed to run syncqt, return code: 2
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/src/corelib/CMakeLists.txt:29 (qt_internal_add_module)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/dyasin/repos/qt6/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/dyasin/repos/qt6/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Where it fails to load English.pm

I have noticed a pecularity that perl uses a different version when compiling for stm. So the build system is using perl from stm SDK. And STM SDK has no English.pm

my question is **how we can use perl from host system**?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. In my toolchain file, I had overridden the "CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH" to find SDK compiler and other programs, I had to adjust it so that it could find perl from host system.